# Snippets Manager

Tags: c++, beginner, c++11, qt

This basically manages a set of snippets, saving and loading it.

**snippets.cpp**

```
#include "Features/snippets.h"
#include <iostream>

Snippets::Snippets(QObject* parent)
    : QObject(parent)
    , m_Snippets(nullptr)
{
    bool success;
    LoadSnippets(success);
}

void Snippets::LoadSnippets(bool& success)
{
    success = false;
    QFile file(SNIPPETS_FILE);

    QMap<QString, QString> data = QMap<QString, QString>();

    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        QDataStream in(&file);
        in >> data;
        file.close();
    }

    if (data.isEmpty()) {
        data.insert(tr("API Help"), tr(
                                        "# Full API\n"
                                        "# ---------------------------\n"
                                        "# get method's have no parameters and others have one\n"
                                        "#\n"
                                        "# get_input   - get input textbox's text\n"
                                        "# set_input   - set input textbox's text\n"
                                        "# get_output  - get output textbox's text\n"
                                        "# set_output  - get output textbox's text\n"
                                        "# get_code    - get code textbox's text\n"
                                        "# set_code    - set code textbox's text\n"
                                        "# write_output- append to output box\n"
                                        "# get_apppath - get exe path\n\n"
                                        "# API Help/Code Sample\n"
                                        "# ---------------------------\n"
                                        "\n"
                                        "# get text from input box\n"
                                        "# parameters - none\n"
                                        "txt = get_input()\n"
                                        "\n"
                                        "# change output box's text\n"
                                        "# parameters - string\n"
                                        "set_output(\"\")\n"
                                        "\n"
                                        "# append to output box\n"
                                        "# does not add a new line\n"
                                        "# parameters - string\n"
                                        "write_output(\"Hi You,\\n\")\n"
                                        "\n"
                                        "# get_apppath() -> get exe path\n"
                                        "print (\"PyRun.exe is at :\", get_apppath())\n\n"));
    }

    m_Snippets = new QMap<QString, QString>(data);

    success = true;
}

void Snippets::SaveSnippets(bool& success)
{
    success = false;
    if (m_Snippets != nullptr) {

        QFile file(SNIPPETS_FILE);
        if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
            return;
        }
        QDataStream out(&file);
        out << *m_Snippets;
        file.close();
        success = true;
    }
}

void Snippets::AddSnippet(const QString& name, const QString& code, bool& success)
{
    success = false;
    if (m_Snippets != nullptr) {
        success = true;
        m_Snippets->insert(name, code);
    }
}

void Snippets::RemoveSnippet(const QString& name, bool& success)
{
    success = false;
    if (m_Snippets != nullptr && m_Snippets->contains(name)) {
        success = (m_Snippets->remove(name) > 0);
    }
}

QString Snippets::GetSnippet(const QString& name, bool& success)
{
    success = false;
    if (m_Snippets != nullptr && m_Snippets->contains(name)) {
        success = true;
        return m_Snippets->value(name);
    }
    return QString();
}

QList<QString> Snippets::GetKeys(bool& success)
{
    success = false;
    if (m_Snippets != nullptr) {
        success = true;
        return m_Snippets->keys();
    }
    return QList<QString>();
}

Snippets::~Snippets()
{
    if (m_Snippets != nullptr) {
        bool success;
        SaveSnippets(success); // save on the destructor
        if (!success) {
            std::cerr << "Writing Snippets to Database on save failed" << std::endl;
        }
        delete m_Snippets;
    }
}
```

**snippets.h**

```
#ifndef SNIPPETS_H
#define SNIPPETS_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QMap>
#include <QList>
#include <QIODevice>
#include <QFile>
#include <QApplication>

#define SNIPPETS_FILE QApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/snippets.dat"

class Snippets : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Snippets(QObject* parent = 0);

    QString GetSnippet(const QString& name, bool& success);
    void RemoveSnippet(const QString& name, bool& success);
    void AddSnippet(const QString& name, const QString& code, bool& success);
    void SaveSnippets(bool& success);
    void LoadSnippets(bool& success);
    ~Snippets();
    QList<QString> GetKeys(bool& success);
signals:

public slots:

private:
    QMap<QString, QString>* m_Snippets;
};

#endif // SNIPPETS_H
```

**What to review:**

- Best practices in C++, C++11, Qt5, and anything else

**Versions/settings:**

- Qt5.3.2
- mingw482_32
- QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11

Comment: Repo https://github.com/JaDogg/expressPython

Comment: Hi, Down voter care to comment ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not being a frequent Qt user, I don't have much to say. But there a few things:

- `SNIPPETS_FILE`: That would be a lot better as a function. Macros and C++ are not a very good match. Macros have quite a few drawback, the most annoying ones are probably not respecting scope and being able to silently redefine them by mistake. I'm not saying that macros don't have [any use whatsoever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041453/why-are-preprocessor-macros-evil-and-what-are-the-alternatives), but C++ offers better alternatives to most cases. A simple function (possibly inline) would be the cleanest solution for this specific case:

  ```
  inline QString GetSnippetsFileName()
  {
      return QApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/snippets.dat";
  }
  ```
- Perhaps you could use a [smart pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) for `m_Snippets` to make your code more exception safe and free yourself from the burden of deallocating the object by hand. But then again, is it really necessary to dynamically allocate `m_Snippets`? Why don't you declared it by value. Avoid a dynamic memory allocation where an instance declared by value will do.
- The way you are returning the result of functions in `SaveSnippets()`, `LoadSnippets()` and others, by passing a `bool& success` to the function, is quite unusual. You should be returning that boolean as the function's return value instead. It would be a lot more conventional. Also, you could consider throwing and exception in some cases.
- I don't think all of the `#include`s in the header file are necessary. `QIODevice` and `QFile` are probably only required by the class implementation in the `.cpp` file. Don't import those dependencies to all users of the class if they are not needed for someone including `snippets.h`.

Comment: Could you please add some references to the first point ? Not because I think it's wrong, I want to do some reading on it. And could you please elaborate more on the second point as well ? Thanks.

Comment: @JaDogg - Sure, there's a lot of discussion about it on SE. Read these links for now. I'll edit the answer with more later on. [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14041453), [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/319452)